# MySQL: different evaluation command line and in mysql console

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line

I was surprised mysql evaluates the same statement differently command line using `mysql -e "$query"` and in the mysql console when you run `mysql` and type queries.
I have a table with timestamp field create_date. I run the same command differently and get different results:

In mysql console:

```
$ mysql -uuser -ppassword database1
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 33608
Server version: 5.5.32-31.0 Percona Server (GPL), Release rel31.0, Revision 549

Copyright (c) 2009-2013 Percona Ireland Ltd.
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select DATE_ADD(create_time, INTERVAL DATEDIFF('2014-03-13', "2013-03-13") DAY) as date from table1;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2014-03-08 00:00:11 |
| 2014-03-08 00:00:22 |
| 2014-03-10 00:00:33 |
| 2014-03-10 00:00:44 |
| 2014-03-12 00:00:55 |
| 2014-03-12 00:00:32 |
| 2014-03-08 00:00:42 |
| 2014-03-08 00:00:23 |
+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The same query from command line using -e parameter gives null results:

```
$ mysql -uuser -ppassword urbanout_www -e 'select DATE_ADD(create_time, INTERVAL DATEDIFF('2014-03-13', "2013-03-13") DAY) as date from table1;'
+------+
| date |
+------+
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
```

Any explanation of this?

Comment: you're using `database1` in your first snippet, and `urbanout_www` in the second one. different DBs, so you're comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: I'll bet anything that's just a copying mistake -- he just forgot to sanitize the database name in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

When you use single quotes in the query, they're terminating the shell's quote, not being sent to MySQL. Try:

```
$ mysql -uuser -ppassword urbanout_www -e 'select DATE_ADD(create_time, INTERVAL DATEDIFF("2014-03-13", "2013-03-13") DAY) as date from table1;'
```